# Non-Equillibrium thermodynamics in rapid evaporation of liquid by laser heating in vacuum chamber

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, evaporation, non-equilibrium

I currently have some results that I am trying to understand. These results show the peak temperature of a crucible (w/ a 10mm diameter) filled with liquid Ag (see diagram). The surface of the liquid is locally heated heated via a continuous-wave laser at various incident laser powers. In addition, I have two additional finite element simulations including heat losses from radiation only ($T^4$) and another including heat losses from radiation and evaporation ($\sqrt{\frac{m}{2\pi k_b T}}\frac{\Delta H_{vap}}{M}p(T) $), as described by the Hertz-Knudsen Equation. ($m$ is the mass of an Ag atom, $\Delta H_{vap}$ is the enthalpy of vaporization, $M$ is the molar mass of Ag and $p(T)$ is the vapor pressure of Ag as a function of temperature.
[image]

I should also note that at laser powers exceeding 500W, rapid evaporation of the liquid Ag occurred. For example, the crucible was filled with 0.4g of Ag each time and and for 1kW, all the Ag was evaporated within 20 seconds. The surface of the liquid also appeared turbulent. This evaporation also took place in a vacuum chamber so we can assume no convection was present at the interface between the liquid and the vapor.[image]

My question is for a system like this, could this system be moving to a non-equilibrium thermodynamics regime, due to rapid evaporation? I am wondering if somehow, either the liquid is not being fully heated, or if more energy is being taken away than what I have accounted for here, which lowers the temperature of the surface. Does anyone have any other ideas regarding where this additional energy loss can come from?

(finally, I should also note that in my simulation, all my thermophysical properties are temperature dependent according to existing data from literature)

EDIT:
The surface temperature was extracted from the deposition rate of Ag upon a substrate inside the vacuum chamber. The melting point of Ag was visually observed at 80W of incident laser power (where vapor pressure is well known). By using the work of I. LangMuir (1913), we know that an order of magnitude in the deposition rate corresponds to an order of magnitude in the vapor pressure, therefore by using the vapor pressure curve of Ag, we can extract approximate vapor pressures and thus obtain surface temperatures.

Comment: Did you measure the apparent surface temperature? If so how?

Comment: @JonCuster The surface temperature was extracted from the deposition rate of Ag upon a substrate, given that the melting point (with a known vp) was observed at 80W of laser power and from the observation that one order of magnitude in deposition rate corresponds to an order of magnitude in the vapor pressure. The vapor pressure curve for Ag can be found here: https://www.iap.tuwien.ac.at/www/surface/vapor_pressure. See the edit for further details

Comment: So you are assuming a saturated vapor, not a superheated vapor?

Comment: @JonCuster yes since as far as I am aware, we are not heating this vapor beyond the normal boiling point of Ag

Comment: Fair enough, I'm more accustomed to solid/liquid interfaces where constitutional superheating/cooling comes into play through an interface response function. The other big question is losing heat to the crucible, particularly since you describe the surface as 'turbulent' - convection seems to come into play.

Comment: Have you evaluated reflection of the laser, conduction through the crucible to the holder, and temperature dependence of material properties as possibly contributing to the discrepancy?

Comment: @Chemomechanics The reflectivity of the Ag surface at the given laser wavelength has been considered and kept at a fixed value. The holder for the crucible was very thin Ta wires so we made the argument that its contribution was negligible. The temperature dependence of all physical properties was considered

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, I will have to consider the convection inside the liquid itself, but this will be fairly difficult to simulate accurately. I suppose for an initial guess, I could find some values of $h$ or liquid Ag, then simply use a $h(T-T_{cruc})$ where T_{cruc} is the average temperature of the crucible

Comment: @JonCuster Another point is that the value of $h$ for convection is not well known in literature for liquid Ag, nor for how $h$ changes with temperature as a constant $h$ would not produce the desired saturation of the temperature seen in the data. Therefore a lot of assumptions would have to be made.

Comment: So test your model - some volume with some thermal diffusivity and heat capacity for the crucible. Not exact values, ballpark. Does that go a long way to resolving the discrepancy? If so, refine the parameters…

Comment: @JonCuster Unfortunately this only helps a bit, but only if I assume that $h$ increases as the temperature increases, but I don't know if this is physically justifiable for this situation